# Devices without hardware MAC addresses

Tags: mac-address

I vaguely remember a comment on the Stack Exchange network saying that some Android devices have no permanent hardware MAC address added at the factory or later on. The comment mentioned that [U-Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot) makes a permanent unchangeable hardware address unnecessary.

Are there Android devices that ship with no permanent hardware MAC address in EEPROM, flash storage, or elsewhere?

Please mind that this question is not about MAC address randomization.

Comment: I don'ts see a comment that would match your description on the linked page. There is one sentence about Ethernet MAC address on that page but Android phones don't have Ethernet.

Comment: @Robert: No, that link was just to clarify what I meant by U-Boot. I can't find the comment in question anymore.